# How can I get old face of spinbox in GTK+3?

Tags: gtk, themes

I have move to gtk+3 for reasons.

However the face of increase and decrease buttons have changed, a lot.

How can I get the old face of those buttons back?

Does the theme engine for gtk+3 is capable to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are various reasons why the layout of `GtkSpinButton` was changed: a better user interaction that does not require precise motion skills, as not everyone is blessed with them, was the major one; scalability of the widget was another reason.

the `GtkSpinButton` layout and rendering has been changed, and the only way to have the old version is to compile against an older version of GTK+, and ship that library with your application.

alternatively you can, if the license permits it, extract the old `GtkSpinButton` code from GTK+ and ship it with your own application.

finally, you can write your own spin button widget that looks and behaves like the old one.

I'd personally recommend none of the above, and just cope with the fact that widgets can change.

Comment: unfortunately, we are not going to do any gtk2 related developping. Gtk3 is the future.

Comment: "older version" does not mean gtk2: you can use an older version of gtk3 prior to the SpinButton redesign. as I said, though, it's not recommended.